# How did the song "Plush" by Stone Temple Pilots get its name?

Tags: meaning, song-title

I've always wondered how the song "Plush" got its name. The lyrics themselves don't  contain the word "Plush" nor do the lyrics and music make me think "Plush" is an appropriate song title. So why is the song called "Plush"?

Answer (score 4):

The song was apparently inspired by the true story of a girl who was kidnapped & murdered, but the lyric was instead turned into a metaphor for a failed obsessive relationship.

So… pure speculation…
The Plush was a soft toy kept by the lyrics' main character, the only physical reminder left of the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'plush' means 'a rich fabric of silk, cotton, wool', which could possibly be reference to the fact that the song is fairly mellowed-out and easy-going. [The lyrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plush_%28song%29#Composition_and_inspiration), however, *have* been explained, and are a metaphor for a failed relationship. The meaning of the title has never been confirmed by Stone Temple Pilots themselves, so it's impossible to get what would be considered a 'true answer'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because he feels soft (plushy) for singing about such a topic as a failed relationship. It's his soft spot?

Comment: This [Rolling Stone article](http://www.rollingstone.com/music/news/plush-stone-temple-pilots) has some background, maybe worth mentioning ?

Answer (score 0):

...or perhaps, *she* was his soft spot. Also, when used as an adjective, *Plush* means "Richly luxurious and expensive". I think *he* (the subject of the song) saw *her* (the object of the song) as a luxuriously beautiful 'thing' that was out of his grasp.